# can't use id and str:username together

Tags: django

I created a blog where you can go to the user's profile and see their posts. You can also see each post separately.

However, I cannot use such url path path ('<str: username> / <post_id> /', post_view, name = 'tak'). This results in Reverse for 'tak' with arguments '(44,)' not error found.
here is my code
views.py

```
def user_posts(request, username):
  posts = Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)
  return render(request, 'profile.html', {'posts':posts})

    
def post_view(request,post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    context={'post':post}
    return render(request, 'post.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
path('<str:username>/', user_posts, name='profile'),
path('<str:username>/<post_id>/', post_view, name='tak'),
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date published',auto_now_add=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
# Create your models here.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}
<ul><li>
{{post}}
<hr>
<p>
<a href="{% url 'tak' post.id %}">{{post}}</a></p>
</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path `tak` expects two arguments, while you send only one: In your `profile.html` replace:

```
<a href="{% url 'tak' post.id %}">{{post}}</a></p>
```

With:

```
<a href="{% url 'tak' request.user.id post.id %}">{{post}}</a></p>
```